# Stretch <img> to fit the entire screen without keeping aspect ratio and without scrollbars

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, size

I am trying to stretch an image in an < img > tag to fit the entire screen independent from aspect ratio. For example, I want it to fit the whole screen both on a 16:9 and a 21:9 screen. I tried the following css as well as `size: 100% 100%;`
Neither of them worked, there are scrollbars on the sides of my browser window.
I want to achieve this: http://nemesisvisuals.com.

As you can see the background image (I am using an < img > tag on purpose so I want the same results but with the < img > tag) stretches to fit the screen no matter what.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            img{
                height: 100vh;
                width: 100vw;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="img.jpg">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/1280/720">
```

Comment: Thank you! I already had margin: 0; in my actual project, and display: block did the trick. padding: 0; doesn't seem to have any impact, but I will leave it there anyway. Thank you :)